# Daemon application with Application Role can't access Endpoint with defined AuthorizeAttribute with the same Role

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory, daemon, azure-ad-msal

My project consists of Web Application, Daemon Application, and Common API for both applications.
This is the definition of application roles in Manifest of App Registration of Common API:

```
"appRoles": [
    {
        "allowedMemberTypes": [
            "Application", "User"
        ],
        "description": "Access the Synchronizator as an application",
        "displayName": "access_as_sync_application",
        "id": "XXX",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "lang": null,
        "origin": "Application",
        "value": "access_as_sync_application"
    },
    {
        "allowedMemberTypes": [
            "User"
        ],
        "description": "Access to everybody timeentries",
        "displayName": "TimeEntries.Administrator",
        "id": "XXX",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "lang": null,
        "origin": "Application",
        "value": "TimeEntries.Administrator"
    },
    {
        "allowedMemberTypes": [
            "User"
        ],
        "description": "Access to own timeentries",
        "displayName": "TimeEntries.User",
        "id": "XXX",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "lang": null,
        "origin": "Application",
        "value": "TimeEntries.User"
    }
],
```

As you can see. I have defined the role "access_as_sync_application" for MemberType "Application" and also for "User" which is used for Daemon Application.
The relationship between both of application is defined in Enterprise applications\API app\Users and groups:
[image]

But once I tried to call API from Daemon application, I am getting 403 forbidden response. This is how I secured the endpoint:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "access_as_sync_application")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<LogSyncResult>> LogSync([FromBody] LogSyncCommand command)
    {
        LogSyncResult result = await Mediator.Send(command);
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

Everything works fine until I used AuthorizeAttribute. I checked the content of access-token and it contains required role:
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't "allowedMemberTypes" for deamon application be set to "Application"? This deamon app runs without user context I assume.

Comment: Please correlation id and time stamp and have you checked this [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-acquire-token?tabs=dotnet)?

Comment: Please try to navigate to the Daemon app -> `API permissions` -> `Add a permission` -> `APIs my organization uses` -> search for the application id of the `Common API` -> add `access_as_sync_application` -> click the `grant admin consent` at last.

Comment: Are you still looking for any help with this question?

Comment: Yes, I do. I just don't have time right now to get back into project in which I am having this problem. Sorry. I will answer y'all soon.